# Append text on rtf string at position

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, richtextbox

I want to append text, for example "World" in a textbox, but not with the `Windows.Forms` functions for `RichTextBox`. Instead i want to specify position and the string that i want to insert into Rtf property of the `RichTextBox`! So, is it possible to update the rtf string directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string rtfStuffs = this.richTextBox1.Rtf;
// Edit as you see fit...
this.richTextBox1.Rtf = rtfStuffs;
```

Comment: Thank you!I find that my problem is something like an Rtf Parser because i don't know where in the rtf format i must insert the new characters.For example i want to made a key Listener wich will add every pressed key into the rtf format directly and not into the RichTextBox form.